# Function to do a clean app restart? corona

Tags: coronasdk

I was just wondering the title. Is there a function to do a complete restart of the app? I know there is in android java. But I am fairly new and cannot seem to find the syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

Corona does not support this feature.

However Corona does support `os.exit()` which completely exits the app.  You could possible have a notification telling users that they will need to relaunch the app, then they click OK on the dialogue and the app quits, then they have to manually restart it.